# Vibration and buzzing when pedaling

Tags: noise, vibration

I have a Sports Inc BZSF3 which is relatively new (hasn't been more than a year). Whenever I am pedaling it starts making a really loud buzz and I feel a vibration. What I've noticed is when I'm dragging it (chain isn't moving) there isn't any noise unless I start running with it which I think is normal, but the slightest push in the pedals and I can feel a vibration and when I'm pedaling fast the noise gets louder and it starts to get extremely obnoxious. What's the problem?

[image: Stock photo of this bike]

Comment: Have you recently greased the chain? If not, do so.

Comment: A clear photo of your drivetrain might help - use [edit] to add one.

Comment: agreed an image of your actual drivetrain may help, my first thought is that something is rubbing somewhere.

Comment: I'd also check the tyres - not just for damage but for something rubbing against the tread (of which there's plenty if the tyres are the ones shown.  Even a cable tie or the end of a shifter cable can cause the frame to vibrate if running against the tread